# ros2 param namespace

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this document:
https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Concepts/About-ROS-2-Parameters.html

It mentions the following

> Parameters are addressed by node name, node namespace, parameter name, and parameter namespace. Providing a parameter namespace is optional.

What exactly is a "parameter namespace"? I can't seem to find any other references to a parameter namespace in ros2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392525/ros2-param-namespace/) by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2021-12-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A parameter namespace can be set when declaring a new parameter, e.g. in Python:

```
self.declare_parameters(
    namespace="ns",
    parameters=[("bar", "default_value")],
)
```

You can then get a parameter in this namespace with:

```
bar = self.get_parameter("ns.bar")
```

The namespace can also be seen as parameter prefix, thus all parameter within a specific namespace can be retrieved with:

```
ns_params = self.get_parameters_by_prefix("ns")
```

---

Originally posted by [philipp_glira](https://answers.ros.org/users/95733/philipp_glira/) with karma: 36 on 2022-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) on 2022-02-10**:
Thanks! I actually forgot I had asked this question. At the time I believe I was confused about why you'd need parameter namespace in addition to the node namespace. I guess it's just another option for organizing node parameters in ROS2. Here's the CPP docs for the same declare_parameters function in case anyone is interested: https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Node.html#a5ebda51ed6fa4ce8f2cddc9f77e9674e
It has some detail on parameter namespaces.